# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, seed

I am trying to seed a many-to-many join table of quests and npcs in those quests... a quest can have many npcs, and an NPC can be used in many quests. I am using Laravel 5.

[image]

When seeding the Quest table, I'm also seeding the join table, but am getting the following error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'clg_local.npc_quest' doesn't exist

Create Quest and Quest_NPC table:

```
public function up()
{
    /*
     * Create quests table
     */
    Schema::create('quests', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('quest_name')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('reward_xp')->nullable();
        $table->string('reward_items')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('reward_money')->nullable();

    });

    /*
     * Create quests_npcs join table
     */
    Schema::create('quest_npc', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('quest_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('npc_id')->nullable();

    });
```

In a separate create, I specify my relations:

```
    Schema::table('quest_npc', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('quest_id')->references('id')->on('quests')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('npc_id')->references('id')->on('npcs')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Clearly I am creating a `quest_npc` table, but it's looking for a `npc_quest` table?

Quest seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $quests = $this->createQuests();

    $npcs = Npc::all()->toArray();

    foreach ($quests as $quest) {

        $quest->npcs()->attach($npcs[rand(0, count($npcs) - 1)]['id']);
    }

private function createQuests()
{
    Quest::unguard();

    $quests = [];

    foreach (
        [
            [
                'quest_name' => 'Quest 1',
                'reward_xp' => 200,
                'reward_items' => null,
                'reward_money' => 200,
            ], ...
```

NPC model:

```
public function npcs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Npc::class);
}
```

Quest model:

```
public function quests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quest::class);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, Laravel 'assumes' the table name to be

> derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names

So in your case, that's the "why".

You can add a second parameter to your `belongsToMany` call to indicate the name you would like to use. For example:

```
public function quests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quest::class, 'quest_npc');
}
```

*Do the above for both relationships*

In my opinion, stick to the convention, unless you need a reason not to.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "stick to the convention"?

Comment: I mean just name your tables in alphabetical order. So in this case 'npc_quest'. Sometimes this is not possible - for example, you might be migrating an old database or application to laravel. But if you are starting from scratch, stick to the convention